# Show that the square root of a non-negative operator is unique

Tags: real-analysis

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, and $A\in B(H\to H)$ be a bounded non-negative operator (i.e. $\langle Ax,x\rangle \geq 0$ for all $x\in H$). The square root of $A$ is a  bounded non-negative operator $B\geq $ such that $B^2=A$.

First, We can assume without loss of generality that $0\leq A\leq I$. Note that $B^2=A$ if and only if 
$$I-B=\frac{1}{2}((I-A)+(I-B)^2).$$
Hence, we definite inductively a sequence $C_n$ of operators as follows: $C_0:=0$, and $C_{n+1}:=1/2((I-A)+C_n^2))$. Then it is easy to see that $C_n$ converges to a bounded non-negetive operator $B$ in the strong operator topology and we also have $B^2=A$, thus the square root exists, but I don't know how to show that it is unique.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose $A$ is a bounded nonnegative operator on a Hilbert space. Let $(p_n)$ be a sequence of polynomials such that
$$
p_n(x) \to \sqrt{x}
$$
uniformly for $x$ in the interval $[0, \|A\|]$ (the Weierstass Approximation Theorem implies the existence of such a sequence of polynomials).

Now suppose $B$ is a nonnegative square root of $A$. Let $\mathcal{B}$ denote the norm closed algebra generated by $B$. Then $\mathcal{B}$ is a commutative $C^*$-algebra that contains $B$ and $A$ (because $A = B^2$). Thus there is a compact Hausdorff space $K$ such that $\mathcal{B}$ is isomorphic as a $C^*$-algebra to $C(K)$. This isomorphism preserves all $C^*$ properties. Thus $A$ corresponds to some nonnegative function $f \in C(K)$ taking values in $[0, \|A\|]$ and $B$ must correspond to the function $\sqrt{f}$ (which is the only nonnegative square root of $f$ in $C(K)$).

Because $p_n \circ f$ converges uniformly to $\sqrt{f}$ uniformly on $K$, we conclude that $p_n(A)$ converges in operator norm to $B$. But the polynomials $(p_n)$ were chosen independently of $B$. Thus $B$ is uniquely determined as a nonnegative square root of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another proof adapted from my prof's lecture notes (maybe it's just a more noob-friendly explanation to Sheldon Axler's answer):

**Step 1: Find a square root operator**

Suppose that $A$ is the non-negative bounded linear operator on our Hilbert space, let
$$
p_n(x)\to\sqrt{x}
$$
be approximating polynomials due to Weierstrass Approximation Theorem, and let
$$
Y=\lim_{n\to\infty}p_n(A)=
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{\lambda\in\sigma_p(A)}p_n(\lambda)P_\lambda ,
$$
where the last equal sign is due to Spectral Theorem:

- $\sigma_p(A)$ is the set of eigenvalues, the so-called point-spectrum of $A$;
- $P_\lambda$ is the orthogonal projection to the eigenspace of eigenvalue $\lambda$;
- We can write $p_n(A)$ like this, because $A^m=(\sum_{\lambda\in\sigma_p(A)}\lambda P_\lambda)^m=\sum_{\lambda\in\sigma_p(A)}\lambda^mP_\lambda$, since $P_\lambda P_\mu = \delta_{\lambda, \mu} P_\lambda$. Also see [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Functional_calculus)).

It can be proven that $Y$ fulfills $Y^2=A$.

**Step 2: Show that it is unique**

Suppose $X$ is another non-negative bounded linear operator such that $X^2=A$, then
$$
XA-AX=X^3-X^3=0 ,
$$
so the elements $A$ and $X$ commute with respect to function composition. This implies that
$$
Xp_n(A)-p_n(A)X=0 \qquad \forall n ,
$$
and
$$
XY-YX=\lim_{n\to\infty}\big(Xp_n(A)-p_n(A)X\big)=0 .
$$

**Claim: $\mathbf{(X − Y)^3 = 0}$**

Because
$$
(X − Y)X(X − Y) + (X − Y)Y(X − Y) \\
= (X^2-Y^2)(X-Y) = (A-A)(X-Y) = 0
$$
and both $(X − Y)X(X − Y)$ and $(X − Y)Y(X − Y)$ are non-negative operators, we have
$$(X − Y)X(X − Y) = (X − Y)Y(X − Y) = 0$$
and thus
$$
(X − Y)^3 = (X − Y)X(X − Y) − (X − Y)Y(X − Y) = 0 .
$$
**Final Steps**

We also have $(X − Y)^4=0$, and
$$
0 = \|(X − Y)^4\| = \|X − Y\|^4 .
$$
This is because $(X − Y)^*=X-Y$ self-adjoint, and $\|T^\ast T\|=\|T^\ast\|\|T\|$ for a bounded linear operator $T$ on a Hilbert space (the so-called [$C^\ast$-identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_algebra#Banach_*-algebras)).

So $X=Y$.